# Setting meeting schedule on future date-time in Bigbluebutton ver 0.9 api

Tags: schedule, bigbluebutton

I have installed Bigbluebutton ver 0.9 in ubuntu14.04 LTS in vmware workstation. The demo meeting works fine but can't set the meeting date for future using api. From documentation I understand that the parameter 'createTime' is to be set for meeting schedule, But can't find any details. Any help or suggested link for api example is highly appreciated

Answer (score 3):

There is no option to schedule a meeting. When create a meeting BigBlueButton give 5 minutes to join the meeting. Within 5 minutes need to join. Otherwise meeting will automatically delete.

Comment: Can you confirm where is it mentioned in the docs.. This is the answer for my problem for past 2 days.

Answer (score -1):

You can try online utility, API Mate **(http://mconf.github.io/api-mate/)** which will create API string for your server and salt with all possible API options.

Hope this helps

Comment: This should be in the comment no the answers,as it doesn't answer the question

Comment: please chek the link it provide the example as requested ,

Comment: I can't find the example

Comment: Above link will need your input like server url,salt,etc and it will generate the request url including createTime parameters

below link will also gives example of createtime parameter in "Join" request

http://docs.bigbluebutton.org/dev/api.html

Comment: the pararameter 'create time' is not for setting the time of the meeting but for cross checking if the created meeting is the same as the joined meeting 
"Third-party apps using the API can now pass createTime parameter (which was created in the create call), BigBlueButton will ensure it matches the ‘createTime’ for the session. If they differ, BigBlueButton will not proceed with the join request. This prevents a user from reusing their join URL for a subsequent session with the same meetingID."